# jQuery scrollTop always returning 0

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div style="height:1280px;"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $('#content').scroll(function(){
        console.log($('#test').scrollTop());

        if($('#test').scrollTop()<=100) {
            $('#header').addClass('shadow');
        }
        else {
            $('#header').removeClass('shadow');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sZ89D/

In it I have a fixed header that will have a class applied to it when the user scrolls a div with an id of test less than it's height (100px). The class is applied but doesn't removed again and console logging the code it turns out that scrollTop is always 0...

Any ideas what the issue is? Thanks

Comment: You are not scrolling `"#test"` so why would it change its scrollTop :/

Comment: It's not the issue in *this* question, but, **another possible cause of scrollTop always returning 0** (and, of setting scrollTop not working and having no effect on prior scroll positions) is, scrollTop doesn't work on hidden elements. For example, if you're fading an element in *and* setting its scroll position, you can have timing issues. For something like `.fadeIn(500).scrollTop(x)`, instead try `.show().css({opacity:0.1}).scrollTop(x).fadeTo(500,1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want the shadow to appear when you scroll down, and disappear when you scroll back to the top?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $('#content').scroll(function(){

                console.log($('#content').scrollTop());

                if($('#content').scrollTop()<=100)
                {
                    $('#header').removeClass('shadow');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#header').addClass('shadow');
                }
            });

        });
```

Swap $('#test').scrollTop() for $('#content').scrollTop(), and reverse the add/remove class functions.

Answer (score 1):

Changing #test to #content seems to do the trick:

```
if($('#content').scrollTop()<=100)
```

Comment: But content isn't moving position!

Comment: You you do scroll in #content.

Comment: @Cameron yes it is - it has the scrollbar. Why did someone downvote this? It's the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
if($('#content').scrollTop()<=100)
                    {
                        $('#header').removeClass('shadow');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#header').addClass('shadow');
                    }
```

Based on comments from @MassivePenguin